# why *y = z binds y to the mem address, but *y = *x takes only a value?

Tags: c, pointers, cs50

I'm trying to understand pointers.
In the code attached I attempted figuring them out by myself but I got a bit more confused.
I do the operation *y = z and I see it make y point to the mem address allocated to z.
but why doesn't *y = *x change the mem address?

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));
    *x = 3;
    int *z = malloc(sizeof(int));
    int *y = z;
    *y = *x;


    printf("x: %i, %p, %p \n y: %i, %p, %p \n z: %i, %p, %p \n", *x, x, &x, *y, y, &y, *z, z, &z);

    free(x);
    free(z);
}
```

Result:

```
x: 3, 0x17b1260, 0x7ffeed5957f8 
 y: 3, 0x17b1280, 0x7ffeed5957e8 
 z: 3, 0x17b1280, 0x7ffeed5957f0
```

Thanks to anyone who answers.

Comment: It might be easier to follow if you keep the assignments away from the definitions. So you could have `int *x` and then `x = malloc(sizeof(int))` (although it is unusual to allocate memory for a single `int`). Similarly instead of `int *y = z;` you could separate it into `int *y;` and then `y = z;`

Comment: In `int *y = z;` you are defining `y` (as a pointer to int) and starting it (`y`) with the value in `z` (also a pointer to int). In `*y = *x;` you are changing `*y` to the value `*x` (you are changing what `y` points to to the same value `x` points to). Initialization and assignment are different operations with slightly different mechanics.

Comment: Thanks to both.

I think that the initialization part got me confused, but now I understand that writing 
int *y = z is just the same as writing y = z, and if i try allocating after initializing  *y = z then my program fails.

so it wasn't that int *y = z was supposed to be assigning the memory of z as the value of *y, but it was actually doing y = z. 

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing an initial value was added on to definitions, so its syntax is a little odd compared to an expression.

In an assignment expression, we write “*thing being assigned* = *value*”, and that is pretty straightforward.

In a simple declaration, we write “*type* *name*” to declare *name* to be an object of type *type*. In a more complicated declaration, instead of a name, we give a sort of sample expression. For example, the declaration “`int` **name*” says **name* is an `int`, which implies *name* must be a pointer to an `int`. The grammar for the declaration is something like “*type* *sample-expression*”, where the declaration tells us that *sample-expression* is of type *type*, and the actual type of the name declared inside the sample expression is deduced.

To add an initialization to that declaration, we append “= *value*”. Then we have “*type* *sample-expression* = *value*”. Because of the way declarations are constructed, this is not saying *sample-expression* is given the value *value*. It says the name within *sample-expression* is initialized with the value *value*.

That odd construction of declarations can be confusing to people learning C, but it is just something you have to become accustomed to.

`int *x = malloc(sizeof(int));` causes `x`, not `*x`, to be initialized with `malloc(sizeof(int))`.

`*x = 3` causes `*x`, not `x`, to be assigned with `3`.